# linux-usb.org submissions - web site broken, emails ignored?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, usb, usb-device

I need to submit some new USB device IDs for addition to the list/kernel.
Does anyone know what has happened to the linux-usb.org list maintainer?

I've attempted to submit new IDs as per the instructions here: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-ids.html

The submissions website https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/ is very broken (im not sure for how long, but at least a couple of weeks).
I've tried emailing linux.usb.ids@gmail.com, but emails have not been read and/or acted upon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had the same experience over the past couple of years. In the end I just gave up.

Comment: Well that's not great to hear.